# Canon 60d is not recording photos to my sd card

Tags: canon, canon-60d, sdcard

My Canon 60d is not recording photos to my sd card.There is 1 CTG file that doesn't open. I formatted the SD card. I have  tried to shoot in RAW and JPEG.Help me! Help Me please!

Answer (score 3):

The CTG file is an internal catalog file created by Canon.

It's very possible that the SD card is bad.

Try reformatting the card in windows, via a card reader. Make sure you don't enable the "Quick Format" option.

If that doesn't work, try a different SD Card.

If that doesn't work, contact Canon for service.